# Hibernate table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have a class with two properties for primary key. I used @IdClass. I am using autowired annotaions. when i tried to save the object it gives 'ORA-00942: table or view does not exist'.

but connections are correct. i am using hibernate session factory. database is oracle

please help me

Comment: Please include your bean class in the post.

Comment: Have you tried logging onto the Oracle server with the credentials you are passing Hibernate to make sure the table is actually visible?

Answer (score 0):

might you be missing privileges to see the table? Oracle gives you 00942 error not only if the table/view don't exist, but also when they don't exist for YOU.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i think this is an application error